# Why do we assume all sample $Y\gt 0$ in uniform distribution of $[0, \theta]$?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, sufficient-statistics

So I am calculating sufficient statistic for uniform distribution on $[0,\theta]$ and $\theta \gt 0$. Sample $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$ has size $n$. I have $L(\theta, Y)=\prod^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{\theta-0} \mathbb{1}(0<Y<\theta)= \frac{1}{{\theta}^n} \mathbb{1}(\min(Y)>0)*\mathbb{1}(\max(Y)<\theta)$. I looked up answer online and discovered we can simply assume $\min{Y}>0$ and take $\max(Y)$ as the sufficient statistics. I know this problem can be solved by using Factorization theorem and taking $g(T(Y), \theta)=\frac{1}{{\theta}^n}\mathbb{1}(\max(Y)<\theta)$ and $h(Y)=\mathbb{1}(\min(Y)>0)$. My confusion is at why can we assume $\min{Y}>0$, I think sample data can certainly be below $0$.

Comment: If you assume (know) that the distribution is on $[0,\theta ]$ then it is impossible that the sample contains a value lower than $0$.

Comment: @callculus If your assumption is true, then I believe $\max(Y)<\theta$ is always true?

Comment: Support of dist'n $Y\sim\mathsf{Unif}(0, \theta),$ where $\theta > 0$ is $(0, \theta).$ so $P(Y< 0) = 0.$ Of course, you can have negative values of $X$ if $X \sim\mathsf{Unif}(-1,1),$ but that is not the given dist'n. // Perhaps looking ahead: If $n = 10,$ and $X_i \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,\theta),$ then $(11/10)\max(X_i)$ is UMVUE of $\theta.$

Comment: @CoolKid Fist of all it is not my assumption. It is the given assumption that $Y\sim [0,\theta]$. Yes,then  it is true as well that $max(Y)\leq \theta$